# MS Access Update Query - To update 1 column on the basis of 3 columns of another table

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables.. and I would like to update 1 column by 3 columns data. So I am currently running 3 queries to update 1 column..
For E.g. Below is the construction of my 2 tables. I would like to update Category in Table 2

Table 1

```
  2_Digit_OUC|3_Digit_OUC | 4_Digit_OUC | Category
------------------------------------------------
    BB       |             |             | Cow
             |     BBC     |             | Dog
             |             |   BBCD      | Cat
```

Table 2

```
 2_Digit_OUC| 3_Digit_OUC| 4_Digit_OUC| Category
 ------------------------------------------------
  BB        | BBD       | BBD1        | Cow
```

Currently I am following below steps:

1. Update Category in Table 2 by 4_Digit_OUC Join
2. Update Category in Table 2 by 3_Digit_OUC Join
3. Update Category in Table 2 by 2_Digit_OUC Join

Can this be done in 1 query?

Comment: Don't understand. There is no field called Category in table 2 so how can you Update Category?

Comment: My bad...I have updated it now..

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Where do values BBD and BBD1 come from? Where did BBC and BBCD go? What rules define how to associate data?